# flashbot unable to decode txs

Tags: go-ethereum

I have using golang to write a flashbot sendBundle method:

```
func SendBundle(rpc string, rawTx string, blockNum *big.Int, pk string) {
    fmt.Println("sending tx", rpc)
    blockDelay := viper.GetInt64("private_buy.block_delay")
    if blockDelay == 0 {
        log.Fatalln("block_delay cannot 0")
    }
    //blockNum + blockDelay
    blockNum = blockNum.Add(blockNum, big.NewInt(blockDelay))

    //blockNum to hex
    blockNumHex := fmt.Sprintf("0x%x", blockNum)

    sendBundleArgs := flashbotsrpc.FlashbotsSendBundleRequest{
        Txs:         []string{"0x" + rawTx},
        BlockNumber: blockNumHex,
    }

    // https://github.com/metachris/flashbotsrpc
    rpcNode := flashbotsrpc.New(rpc)
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(pk)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to parse private key", err)
    }
    result, err := rpcNode.FlashbotsSendBundle(privateKey, sendBundleArgs)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
}
```

I have encode uniswap tx with following:

```
//uniswapV2Router is a Go Contract Binding
tx, err = uniswapv2Router.SwapExactETHForTokens(txOpts, amountOutMin, path, publicKeyAddress, big.NewInt(now))

txBytes := &bytes.Buffer{}

err = tx.EncodeRLP(txBytes)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

rawTx := hex.EncodeToString(txBytes.Bytes())
```

but error:

```
{"error":"unable to decode txs"}
```